# How to tell curl to use one client cert from the Windows Cert Store?

Tags: windows, curl, ssl-certificate

Disclaimer: I am new to curl.

When I go to https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/ with Chrome, I am asked by Chrome to choose one client cert among the few ones I currently have in my Windows Cert Store.
[image: Chrome wants me to choose a client cert]

Once I have choose a Cert, cryptomix.com is happy.

[image: https result]

Fine. Now I have a curl shipped with Windows
[image: curl shipped with my Windows 11 64 bits]

BUT THEN, if I just `curl https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/` cryptomix is NOT happy.
[image: no cert presented]

How do I tell curl to use a certain client cert from my Windows Cert Store?

Comment: If the question is more suitable for Super User, how do you migrate the question there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1756409/how-to-tell-curl-to-use-one-client-cert-from-the-windows-cert-store).

The trick is to NOT prefix the Cert Path with "CurrentUser".

> ```
> c:\Windows\System32>curl.exe --cert
> "\\MY\\7cbcaf1586e5a1cb9ba72aa7deed294ca4779266"
> https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/
> ```